# How to upload an image from vue js to django rest framework?

Tags: django, image, vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuejs2

I am using django-rest-framework as my backend and I want to upload an Image from the frontend(vuejs2)
note: the backend works perfectly and I can upload the photo using django admin

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your backend accept `multipart/form-data` and using `axios`

```js
<input type="file" @change="onFileChange" />

export default {
  methods: {
    onFileChange(e) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", e.target.files[0]);
      axios
        .post("/upload", formData)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("SUCCESS");
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log("FAILED");
        });
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response sending a formdata made it work because I was sending the data in a form instead of a formdata